# Mockito verify method call with generic collection argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have this method:

```
public void myMethod(Set<Item> items);
```

When I try to call:

```
Mockito.verify(instance.myMethod(Mockito.anySet());
```

I get this compilation error:

> The method verify(T) in the type Mockito is not applicable for the arguments (void)

I get the same error even when I define an argument captor. How can I fix this?

Comment: change void to datatype which is the argument typefor verify method and return it from your myMethod

Comment: I've voted to close this question, because the solution had very little to do with generic collection arguments and much more to do with syntax differences in `when` and `verify`. Really happy you got it solved, though. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. It has to be like this:

```
Mockito.verify(instance).myMethod(Mockito.anySet());
```

The parentheses were wrongly placed.